# find the minimum value of $(a+\frac{1}{a})^{10}+(b+\frac{1}{b})^{10}+(c+\frac{1}{c})^{10}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

If $a,b,c$ are positive such that $a+b+c=1$ find the minimum value of

$(a+\frac{1}{a})^{10}+(b+\frac{1}{b})^{10}+(c+\frac{1}{c})^{10}$

I did $f(x)=(x+\frac{1}{x})^{10}$ which is concave up in $(0,\infty)$ so by Jensen

$f(\frac{1}{3} (a+b+c))=f(\frac{1}{3}) \leq \frac{1}{3}(f(a)+f(b)+f(c))$ so

$\frac{10^{10}}{3^9}$ is the minimum, but i dont know if this is right

Comment: What's the point of this post? Do you want us to check your solution? Propose a different solution?

Comment: @TheBestMagician check my solution, sorry i forget to write it

Comment: Yep... your solution is correct.  By interchange symmetry, $a = b = c = 1/3$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't think the symmetry of the expression helps, unless you have some form of convexity anyway. Is there a problem, prima facie, with having minima achieved at, say, only $(a, b, c) = (0.5, 0.25, 0.25), (0.25, 0.5, 0.25), (0.25, 0.25, 0.5)$?

Comment: $f(x)$ is convex, not concave. The rest of the solution is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Jensen's inequality is brilliant. A non-olmypiad way is method of Lagrange's multipliers, $f_{x_i}=\lambda g_{x_i}, i\in I$ applied to the function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\sum_i={1}^{3}(x_i+\frac1{x_i})^{10}$ under the constraint $g(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\sum_{i=1}^3x_i=1.$ Then we have the system
$$10(x_i+\frac1{x_i})^9(1-\frac1{x_i^2})=\lambda.$$
It has the unique solution $x_1=x_2=x_3=\frac13$ since the function
$h(x)= 10(x+\frac1{x})^9(1-\frac1{x^2})$ is increasing on $(0,1)$. Right?